# Getting HTTP 400: Bad Request when trying to connect to local DynamoDB with Kotlin

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb, ktor

I'm using [AWS Kotlin client libraries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/setup.html) from Kotlin and Ktor. When trying to connect to a local DynamoDB instance running in Docker I get the following error message:

```
 DEBUG httpTraceMiddleware - DynamoDB-GetItem-835467a5-aedc-40ab-8c28-b56b625ccbd4/Attempt-1: HttpResponse: 400: Bad Request
```

I'm using the library version `aws.sdk.kotlin:dynamodb:0.18.0-beta` and my DynamoDB client configuration is the following. I used the [sample provided in their official guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/kotlin_dynamodb_code_examples.html) as a baseline.

```
suspend fun getValueForKey(tableNameVal: String, keyName: String, keyVal: String) {

    val keyToGet = mutableMapOf<String, AttributeValue>()
    keyToGet[keyName] = AttributeValue.S(keyVal)

    val request = GetItemRequest {
        key = keyToGet
        tableName = tableNameVal
    }
    val provider = StaticCredentialsProvider.Builder().apply {
        accessKeyId = "fakeMyKeyId"
        secretAccessKey = "fakeSecretAccessKey"
    }.build()

    DynamoDbClient {
        credentialsProvider = provider
        region = "us-east-1"
        endpointUrl = Url.parse("http://localhost:8000")
    }.use { ddb ->
        val returnedItem = ddb.getItem(request)
        val numbersMap = returnedItem.item
        numbersMap?.forEach { entry ->
            println(entry.key)
            println(entry.value)
        }
    }
}
```

I even tried adding fake access/secret keys [based on the official guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html), but the result is the same. So even if I don't specify the `credentialsProvider` parameter I get the same error.
From the command line, I'm able to perform a successful operation using the command below:

```
aws dynamodb get-item \
    --table-name key_values \
    --key '{"key": {"S": "key1"}}' \
    --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out there are mainly two reasons for such exceptions:

1. Using the wrong region, access key, and secret key for table creation & read/write
2. Not having a proper endpoint configured

**Proper endpoint configuration**

I had to create a "fake" `EndpointProvider` that returns a static local endpoint. Using the `endpointUrl` property of `DynamoDbClient` did not work for me. Skipping `credentialsProvider` also leads to a `CredentialsProviderException`.

**Getting the Region, Access Key & Secret Key Right**

I had to specify the region, access & secret key pairs on every operation. Missing any of that might lead to a scenario where incorrect configuration is read from `.aws/credentials` file or from environment variables mixing up the read/write or table creation operations. It seems, that the local DynamoDB returns an *"HTTP 400 Bad Request"* if access/secret key pairs or the target region are not the same when the table is created.

**Example Command For Table Creation**

```
#!/bin/bash
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=DUMMYIDEXAMPLE
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=DUMMYIDEXAMPLE
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2

aws dynamodb create-table \
    --table-name key_values \
    --attribute-definitions AttributeName=key,AttributeType=S \
    --key-schema AttributeName=key,KeyType=HASH \
    --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 \
    --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

**Example Command For Reading Table in Kotlin**

The `accessKeyId`, `secretAccessKey`, and `region` attributes has to be the same as above.

```
    val credentials = StaticCredentialsProvider.Builder().apply {
        accessKeyId = "DUMMYIDEXAMPLE"
        secretAccessKey = "DUMMYIDEXAMPLE"
    }.build()

    val endpoint = EndpointProvider { Endpoint(Url.parse("http://localhost:8000")) }

    DynamoDbClient {
        credentialsProvider = credentials
        region = "us-west-2"
        endpointProvider = endpoint
    }.use { ddb ->
        val returnedItem = ddb.getItem(request)
        val numbersMap = returnedItem.item
        numbersMap?.forEach { entry ->
            println(entry.key)
            println(entry.value)
        }
    }
```